# IPC Message queue question marks in the received message

Tags: c, unix, command-line, queue, ipc

Good Evening.

I was trying to reproduce example of sending and retrieving messages using IPC Queue.
The problem is when I am printing the message f.ex."aaaa" i see as output "????".

receiver.c

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int msqid;

```
int rc;
size_t msgsz;
struct {
    long int mtype;
    char * mtext;
} mymsg;

long int msgtype;

msqid = msgget(65536, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
struct mymsg message;

msgsz = sizeof(struct mymsg) - sizeof(long int);
msgtype = 1;
for (;;) {
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &message, msgsz, msgtype, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
    }
    puts(message.mtext);
}

printf("Error code: \"%d\"\n", rc);
printf("The message received is: \"%s\"\n", message.mtext);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

send.c

```
int rc;
    size_t msgsz;
    struct {
      long int mtype;
      char * mtext;
    } mymsg;

    long int msgtyp;

    msqid = msgget(65536, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);


    mymsg.mtype = 1;
    mymsg.mtext = argv[1];

    struct mymsg message;

    msgsz = sizeof(struct mymsg) - sizeof(long int);

    //rc = msgsnd(msqid, &mymsg, msgsz, IPC_NOWAIT);

    while(fgets(mymsg.mtext, sizeof mymsg.mtext, stdin) != NULL) {
            int len = strlen(mymsg.mtext);

            /* ditch newline at end, if it exists */
            if (mymsg.mtext[len-1] == '\n') mymsg.mtext[len-1] = '\0';

            if (msgsnd(msqid, &mymsg, len+1, 0) == -1) /* +1 for '\0' */
                perror("msgsnd");
        }

        if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("msgctl");
            exit(1);
        }
```

This is my very beginning with C - language.
I want to extend this to more complicated program.

I was following beej documentation.
http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mq.html

I cannot find anything about those question marks or maybe its a lack of knowledge.

Will appreciate all clues.

Greetings.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for mtext.  Change the structure definition to user `char mtext[16]`

Comment: both the 'send.c' and the 'receiver.c' are missing the needed include statements for the required header files.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameters were actually entered

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { int msqid;` and similar lines.  For ease of readability and understanding follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when calling system functions, for instance: `msgget()`, `msgrcv()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when defining a struct, always include a 'tag name' because that is what most debuggers use to be able to display the individual fields in the struct

Comment: the posted code, is defining a struct AND an instance of the struct named `mymsg`.  This is not what you want to be doing.  especially later in the code with this statement: `struct mymsg message;`  which is expecting the 'tag name' of the struct to be `mymsg`.

Comment: regarding: `    struct
    {
        long int mtype;
        char * mtext;
    } mymsg;`  the pointer: `mtext` should be declared as `char mtext[1024];`  because that is the actual memory to be sent/received.  This is probably the main reason that trash is being received, because a pointer in the sender means nothing in the receiver

Comment: the `send.c` code is missing the include statements for the needed header files.   and it is missing some code at the end of the posted function.

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(mymsg.mtext, sizeof mymsg.mtext, stdin) != NULL) {`  the expression: `sizeof mymsg.mtext` will evaluate to the size of a pointer (say 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the underlying hardware architecture) The function: `fgets()` always inserts a trailing NUL byte and since reading from `stdin`, probably also has a '\n' inserted before the NUL byte.  This means the user (assuming 4 byte pointers) will only be able to insert 2 characters.

Comment: The message type field of the struct field: `mtype` should be int32_t (from the header file `stdint.h`  not `long int`

Comment: strongly suggest reading/understanding the MAN pages for each of the functions being called.

Comment: regarding the question marks being printed, that means that the data that is trying to be printed is not a printable character